# Is it ok to test ads on simulator with real Admob ids before uploding to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am going to upload my application. I am using Google mobile ads in my app and I am testing via test ads ids. Now before deploying I have to put real admob ids in app for test. Is it OK to test ads after putting real ids on simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have tested the functionality and ads were working with test id's then you can just use the production id's and it doesn't matter where you run the app then simulator/device.

Comment: alright and if test the ad with real ids ..could it effect my admob account?

Comment: It will show the ads even on simulator. But don't click repeatedly. Long time ago, it used to add those pennies into your account but after some it used to deduct as their algo's are smart enough to know how clicks count.